# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent SSR React + Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm tryna update this document on firebase it works for the first time but after that it gives me this error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

This the button which toggles the value:

```
getActionButtons = () => {
    if(this.state.stepIndex > 2){
      return (<ActionButtons>
        <ActionButton label={this.state.userType === 'Rider' ? this.state.available ? 'Found a carpool?' : 'look for carpool' : this.state.available ? 'Car is Full?' : 'Available for carpool'} primary={!this.state.available} secondary={this.state.available} onClick={() => {
         console.log("eventId: ", this.props.eventId.event)
          console.log("userId: ", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
          // firebase.database().ref('/' + this.props.eventId.event + '/posts/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).transaction((post => {
          //   if (post) {
          //     if (post.available) {
          //       post.available = !post.available
          //     } else {
          //       post.available = this.state.available
          //     }
          //   }
          //   return post;
          // }))
          firebase.database().ref('/' + this.props.eventId.event + '/posts/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/available').set(!this.state.available)
          this.setState({
            available: !this.state.available
          });
          this.props.update();
        }}/>
      </ActionButtons>)
    }
  }
```

Server Code:

```
const activeRoute = routes.find(route => matchPath(req.url, route)) || {}
const isEventPage = activeRoute.name === "carpoolingPage"


app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
if(isEventPage) {
    if (req.params[0]) {
      let eventRef = firebase.database().ref(req.params[0])
      eventRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {
        const event = snapshot.val()
        // console.log("event: ", event)
        if(!event)
          res.redirect("/eventnotfound")
        else {
          const { title, location, description } = event
          const preloadedState = { currentEvent: event }
          const store = configureStore(preloadedState)
          const markup = generateMarkup(store)
          res.send(HTML({
            title: `Carpooling to ${ title }`,
            markup, styleTags,
            preloadedState,
            ogTitle: `Carpooling to ${ title }`,
            ogDescription: `Find people to carpool with to ${ title }. Choose to ride or drive to ${ location } ${ description === null ? '' : `Event Description: ${ description }`}`
          }))
        }
      })
    }
  }
  else {
    const store = configureStore()
    const markup = generateMarkup(store)
    res.send(HTML({ markup, styleTags }))
  }
})
```

I'm using SSR with Node and React and the express server only uses cors().

FYI, it toggles the value properly on firebase the problem that the server exits with the error above which cause the code that follow it doesn't run.

BTW, I've tried to use firebase transactions and tried to remove the code after the firebase line but it gives the same error.

I've followed all the similar questions on stack overflow but it doesn't match my problem.

Comment: The error is from the Express.js code for sure. Can you share that route's code?

Comment: Would u check it now  ?

Comment: Do you have any other API calls?

Comment: Can you check the error once. And see which line the code is breaking?

Comment: no just this ..

Comment: breakes after after updating something on firebase

Comment: I don't know the firebase. But I'm sure that `eventRef.on("value", ...)` is happening more that one time. And your `res.redirect` or `res.send` is being called more than one time. In express, if you responded once you can't respond again. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Bro This hint helped me I replaed it with once would you insert it as an answer to give you your credit. I will sign it as the right answer .

Comment: Great. I've added it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that `eventRef.on("value", ...)` is happening more that one time. And your `res.redirect` or `res.send` is being called more than one time. In express, if you responded once you can't respond again. Hope this will solve your problem.

Make the `evetRef.on` to `eventRef.once`. This will solve your problem.